# SendGrid-PHP Library and Laravel 4.2 integration error

Tags: php, laravel, email, composer-php, sendgrid

After composer update with the [sendgrid-php repo](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) this error is received `Missing argument 1 for SendGrid\Email::__construct()` per `public function __construct($name, $email)`.

Emails are sent fine via SMTP, but I'm looking to use the extended options so trying to use this library.

The documentation is light. Is an autoload service provider required and class alias?

Comment: My guess is they updated the package for Laravel 5 and changed the API. Laravel 5 has major implementation changes for it's own API and service providers. Which version of Sendgrid are you importing? if 5.0, I suggest rolling back to 4.* and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I was moving so fast I didn't even notice. You are right. I'm moving to 4.0.4 and I'm sure that will do the trick. Will confirm